# Why are SRTM tiles (*.tif) not visible in my QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, srtm

I am wondering, why my SRTM tiles are not displaying correctly in my QGIS (3.10.4 LTR) project. If I load vector layers to an empty QGIS project first, they are visible and the later added SRTM are not visible. Other raster layers are visible.

The problem exists also vice versa: If I load the SRTM tiles into an empty QGIS Project first, they are displayed correctly. But if I load vector layers later to that project, the vector layers don't show up...

Comment: Your layers are just not visible or they aren't even added?

Comment: this look like a projection problem, check that the projection of your tif and vector are correctly defined

Comment: Ok it works now, thanks